# Google Sheets Formula Randomly Assign Values To A Column Skipping Row If Adjacent Cell = "Down"

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have 3 columns whose values are randomly generated using this formula

```
=sort(A1:A36,arrayFormula(randbetween(sign(row(A1:A36)),1000000)),true)
```

and displayed in columns (H,I,J) and I would like to copy these values into 3 new columns (L,M,N) but skipping the entire row if an adjacent cell within the row = "Down" (Column O).

Below is a screenshot of my current state and problem.

[image: current]

Below is a screenshot of what I want to accomplish using an excel formula.  I currently just pasted the values to use as a reference of what I would like to accomplish.

[image: goal]

Comment: Can you please add proper formatting to your question?

Comment: Sorry first time posting here...is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to copy the data from some columns to some other columns, but skipping the rows where the O column is "Down". Not really specific to randomness of those values. Here is my approach:

```
=if(O2 <> "Down", offset(H$1, countif(O$1:O1, "<>Down"), 0, 1, 3), )
```

The `offset` gets three cells in the row determined by `countif`, which is based on the number of cells that are not "Down" above the current row. This formula would need to be entered on the second row and copied down. I wasn't able to find a solution that gives the entire array at once with some `arrayformula`.